# Copying file from Remote server to local and vice versa

Tags: asp.net

thanks for ur quick response. but im stucked with login only. im using following code to try to login:

```
bool success = LogonUser("username", "000.000.000.000", "#####",2 ,0 , out userToken);
```

but im getting exception as failed
im using username and pwd which i use to login via mstsc.

Im writing code to copy files from remote machine to local machine and vice versa.
but im not able to know how can i specify credentials to do so..
my code is following:

```
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(globalInfo.GlobalServerPath, sourcePath ));
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(globalInfo.GlobalPath, destPath)


string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFile);

foreach (string s in files)
  {
   string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
  fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(destFile, fileName);
 System.IO.File.Copy(s, fileName, true);
 }
```

here i get error : **Could not logon..**

for line

**string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFile);**

im connecting to remote machine.

Please help

Comment: You don't have the appropriate permission to log in. You'll need to specify a UNC path containing the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

you need impersonation :

```
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(
            string lpszUsername,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            out IntPtr phToken);

IntPtr userToken = IntPtr.Zero;

bool success = External.LogonUser(
  "john.doe", 
  "domain.com", 
  "MyPassword", 
  (int) AdvApi32Utility.LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, //2
  (int) AdvApi32Utility.LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, //0
  out userToken);

if (!success)
{
  throw new SecurityException("Logon user failed");
}

using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userToken))
{
  // do the stuff with john.doe's credentials
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur quick response. but im stucked with login only.

Comment: you should set the username and the password in the code ive gave you ,

Comment: down vote favorite
share [fb] share [tw]
 

thanks for ur quick response. but im stucked with login only. im using following code to try to login:

bool success = LogonUser("username", "000.000.000.000", "#####",2 ,0 , out userToken);

but im getting exception as failed im using username and pwd which i use to login via mstsc.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar scenario in our project. We have created a user on the domain which has required permission on local and remote server (both servers in same domain). We have a windows service as well as web application both configured to run under this user context. Hence we don't get permission issues when coping the file to and from remote server.

However if the remote server is not on the same domain, then you either user Impersonation(if possible) or configure a ftp server on remote machine. You can then upload and download files using ftp protocol.

Comment: down vote favorite
share [fb] share [tw]
 

thanks for ur quick response. but im stucked with login only. im using following code to try to login:

bool success = LogonUser("username", "000.000.000.000", "#####",2 ,0 , out userToken);

but im getting exception as failed im using username and pwd which i use to login via mstsc.